# How to copy multiple files but keep their extensions the same?

Tags: shell, scripting, rename, wildcards, file-copy

I am looping through a number of files, and `$file` represents the current file.

How can I make copies or renames and keep the extension the same for this current file?

e.g. if `$file` = `x.jpg`

How to make a copy of `$file`'s with a filename of `x_orig.jpg`

So far I have:

```
for file in /tmp/p/DSC*.JPG; do
  cp $file $file+'_orig'.JPG
done
```

but that copies the file

```
DSCF1748.JPG
```

to

```
DSCF1748.JPG+_orig.JPG
```

whereas I want a copy named

```
DSCF1748_orig.JPG
```

Similarly, using `cp $file "$file"_orig.JPG`

results in files such as `DSCF1748.JPG_orig.JPG`

I want to get the `_orig` in the middle of the filename...

Comment: THe is posted on your previous questio. This is double posting.

Comment: I rolled back your edit because it is generally a good idea to quote variable names, you never know what they might contain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use bash's [string substitution features](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for that:

```
for file in /tmp/p/DSC*.JPG; do
  cp "$file" "${file%.JPG}"_orig.JPG
done
```

The general format is `${string%substring}` which will remove `substring` from the end of `string`. For example:

```
$ f=foobar.JPG; echo "${f%.JPG}"
foobar
```

Comment: You should use `"${file%.JPG}"` instead. `f` is not defined, `file` is. Furthermore (as you mentioned), the `/%.abc/` syntax is a bash feature. Dropping the slashes works for this case and makes it POSIX compatible, which makes sense, since conversion scripts often use a POSIX shell.

Comment: @Marco thanks, answer edited. The `f` was just a typo left over from the example I was trying. Thanks for letting me know about the POSIX side though, I thought the whole substitution thing was specific to bash.

Comment: How can I make this match multiple files, and copy then but keeping the extension?

Answer (score 2):

```
zcp -o -p '/tmp/p/DSC*.JPG' '$f:r_orig.JPG'
```

or equivalently

```
zcp -o -p '/tmp/p/(DSC*).JPG' '/tmp/p/${1}_orig.JPG'
```

This requires that you run zsh (other shells have nothing like this) and put this in your `~/.zshrc`:

```
autoload -U zmv
alias zcp='zmv -C'
alias zln='zmv -L'
```

`-o -p` tells `zcp` to pass the option `-p` to the `cp` command, to preserve the file metadata (especially the modification times).